# What is the mechanism of platinum as catalyst poisons on alumina?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, catalysis

I'm wondering if anyone knows by what mechanism is platinum (or other noble metals) catalyst on alumina substrate poisoned?

Presently, I'm using platinum on alumina to decompose a hydrogen peroxide / $
\ce{KNO3}$ solution and have found the catalyst material poisoned.  I'm wondering if the poisoning is due to the $\ce{KNO3}$ or if my peroxide is contaminated.

I can imagine $\ce{KNO3}$ crystallizing and thereby occluding the active sites on the alumina but I'm not a chemist, so I've come here looking for better insight.